# MiniProfiler uninstall error

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I cannot uninstall the MiniProfiler from my project. It always gives me this error message 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'MiniProfiler' is undefined' and inserts dynamic JavaScript code into my html page. It is on IE9 when I press the backward button of the browser.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following lines of code to your web.config file it should sort the problem out:

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" 
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"
         resourceType="Unspecified" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I noticed the exact same error when using a **MiniProfiler** with an **MVC 4** application. This fixed it for me. For more information, check out the **MiniProfiler** forum:

http://community.miniprofiler.com/permalinks/113/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-miniprofiler-is-undefined